# How to make Android app secure for payment system?

Tags: android, pci-compliance, pci-dss

I am developing an Android app that selling mobile credits over the internet.
My app just keeps user credit card information and never saving any password.
I am in Iran and my country isn't accept any foreign banking system.So I can use only local payment system and I can't use any third party API out there over the Internet.
I'm struggling how to make my app secure according to PCI documentation. 
I googling a lot and find some solution out there but I am not sure if it is an effective solution in Iran.
Here is some solutions that I found:

> [How to store data into Secure Element in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102526/how-to-store-data-into-secure-element-in-android)
>
> [Secure element Access Control on ICS 4.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494726/secure-element-access-control-on-ics-4-0-4)
>
> [Java Card Applet and Host-based Card Emulation of Android Kitkat 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319619/java-card-applet-and-host-based-card-emulation-of-android-kitkat-4-4)

[PCI DSS compliant related to the Mobile Application payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112035/pci-dss-compliant-related-to-the-mobile-application-payment)

So any help will be appreciated.